# Use fields from WhatID object in Email Template

Tags: apex, email-template, send-email, whatid

I have apex code that sends out emails using templates. The code sets the RelatedTo id as a contact, and the WhatID as a custom object which is a child of contact. Sometimes the child object is a child of the RelatedTo object, and sometimes it's not.

When I test the merge fields for the email template, it works correctly, but when the email actually gets sent out, if there is no child object for the related to object, the merge fields are null. 
I really need the merge fields to be pulled from the child object (which is referenced by the WhatID), even if it is a child of a different contact.

Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: you may need to use visualforce email template.

Comment: @Ratan: and then select the relevant info in soql?

Comment: Yes correct. You can use controller and based on that get all childs

Comment: Ok - please add this as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO you could use Visualforce email template.

In Visualforce email template use VF component and controller.

In controller based `RelatedTo` get all childs and show then in VF controller.

Use this VF component in Visualforce email template.

Example: http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/05/visualforce-email-template-with-custom.html

Comment: How do I access the whatId from the template?

Comment: @hgolov you can pass the `whatId` from email template to component using `apex variable`  check above mentioned example